# What should we tag the Steam Summer Sale Monster Game?

Tags: discussion, tags

So we're getting questions now on the Steam Summer Sale incremental game. Right now questions are getting tagged with [steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam). Is that how we want to tag it? Or should we go with something else?

Possible Options:

- [steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam) - As it is now
- [monster-summer-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-summer-game) - Title on main page for game
- [monster-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-game) - Title in game
- [steam-monster-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-monster-game) - Combo of title plus "Steam" for findability?
- [tower-attack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tower-attack) - Silly, but it's the title of the game in the URL

Comment: So Steam doesn't have a consistent name for it? Well, that makes things so much more fun :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think we should go with [steam-monster-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-monster-game) so that users typing in "steam" will see it in the autocomplete list

Comment: This is probably the best option. `monster-summer-game` just doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would go with [monster-summer-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-summer-game). Seems to be the most "official" title

Comment: Summer Sale > Summer Game Info > Monster Game. So i think Monster game would be most official title.