# How does a tag get chosen between two possible candidates?

Tags: discussion

An example right now would be [doom-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doom-4) and [doom-2016](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doom-2016) for the newest Doom game. Is it just a matter of letting users decide and then delete/alias the less popular one? I'm pretty new to how all this works.

Answer (score 4):

[doom-2016](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doom-2016) should be chosen as that is the actual name of the game, not Doom 4. Doom 4 should be a synonym, since it is sort of an informal name and most people will probably recognize it as the same game.

Comment: Generally, if a publisher decides to screw numbering for whatever reason (maybe they're ashamed to have made so many) and call the n-th game the same as the first, the date is appended. See also [tag:sw-battlefront-2015].

Answer (score 0):

It usually gets voted on meta, and the higher-voted one gets picked. Other one usually gets added as an alias to that. A good example can be found [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10612/what-should-we-tag-the-steam-summer-sale-monster-game).

FWIW, I vote [doom-2016](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doom-2016)